# Why have we not run out of IP addresses?

Tags: ip

I am learning about the Internet (with the capital I, which is different from internet) and there is something very very strange that I don't fully understand.

As I get it, every computer on the Internet must have an IP address, so that if I want to search on google, I will have to know google's address to ask it. Of course, I don't have to remember google's actual address, I can ask my local nameserver via resolvers and it will figure out the address on its own. But that means that my computer must also have a unique IP address, which is very strange since there are lots of other computers from other people, and the number of devices are well above the 4 billion addresses allowed by IPv4. IPv6 deployment progress is currently at 30% so that can't be the explanation.

I later found out that most devices are connected to the Internet via an ISP. In my understanding, an ISP have a unique address, assigns a number (different than the IP address) to my device, then sends out requests (with flags that identify the request is coming from me) to computers at google. When it (the ISP) retrieves a response, it reads the flag and it knows that it's supposed to give the answer back to me and not someone else. Is this how it actually works? That every ISP in the world has a static IP address.

Also very strange is that last week, I tried messing around with DigitalOcean and their droplets. I managed to set up a simple web server. I have worked with websites before, but all of my work was through cPanel and I don't really understand anything underneath. DigitalOcean then gave me a single, simple unique IP address (IPv4) that I can go to to see the website. I checked with my friends to see if they are seeing the same thing or not, and they did. How is this possible? I am surely not the only customer on DigitalOcean and this simple project is surely not the only project they are serving so how can they assign my website with a unique IP address?

And to add to that, why is IPv4 exhaustion a problem when you can do things like this? I have heard of ways that servers can delay this problem. Can someone elaborate how can they do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IPv4 address is four bytes, or four numbers ranging from 0-255.

256^4 = 4,294,967,296
[Population of Internet users (May 21st 2018)](https://internetworldstats.com/stats.htm): 4,383,810,342 which was an increase by over 1114% in 19 years.

Include reserved addresses, and we’d be completely out if we hadn’t already started rolling out IPv6. 
In essence, assuming 30% of those 4.4 billion are on IPv6, then that’s 3.1 billion on IPv6, which is a good amount under 4.3 billion. It seems we’re rolling out IPv6 at the rate it’s needed, and as IPv6 rolls out, IPv4 frees up.

Edit:

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/768067/why-are-we-still-stuck-on-ipv4-when-we-are-ipv6-ready#768086) for what seems to be a more informed answer.